# Looking for url rewrite using IIS

Tags: proxy, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, reverse-proxy, iis-8

https://my-public-url.com  is just a public url and it is pointing to my public ip server (20.23.45.67:443)

my dev url : https://my-Dev-url.local (it points to the web application in ex: 10.99.11.20:1562)
my QA url : https://my-QA-url.local   (it points to the web application in ex: 10.99.11.20:2678)
my UAT url: https://my-UAT-url.local   (it points to the web application in ex: 10.99.11.20:3456)

When I click on the url https://my-public-url.com/Dev  it should redirect to my dev url
When I click on the url https://my-public-url.com/QA  it should redirect to my Qa url
When I click on the url https://my-public-url.com/UAT  it should redirect to my UAT url

Is it possible to achieve the above requirement using IIS proxy rules, if yes please help me how to do that

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could refer to below rewrite rule.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy to Dev" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^Dev/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://my-Dev-url.local/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy to QA" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^QA/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://my-QA-url.local/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy to UAT " stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^UAT/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://my-UAT-url.local/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

More details, you could refer to beblow article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Thanks for the response Brando.
I have tried the above code which did not work for me, I keep trying in different ways but somewhere I got missed the correct config.

Comment: Could you please tell me how this config not work for you? Does it show any error message?

Comment: It gave me 404 error.
But after trying multiple ways , finally i got a solution for my requirement.
<rule name="Rewrite to Dev page">
     <match url="^Dev(.*)" />
     <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^my-public-url.com$" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="http://my-Dev-url.local/{R:1}" />
   </rule>

Answer (score 0):

```
Finally, this works for me.
<rule name="Rewrite to Dev page">
<match url="^Dev(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^my-public-url.com$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://my-Dev-url.local/{R:1}" />
</rule>`
When I click on https://my-public-url.com/Dev  it is redirecting to my local url
```